# Keeping original view orientation when moving into a transformed view

Tags: ios, uiview, cgaffinetransform

[image]

[image]

[image]

In picture 1, I have a UIView called parentView1 (it is the gray color view).  It has subviews (4 in the picture).

Before I applied CGAffineTransformRotate to parentView1, I can drag a view (the red vertical) and drop into parentView1 and the result is as picture 2.

However, if I first do a CGAffineTransformRotate (see code) on parentView1, then drag and drop to add the red vertical view into the parentView1, the red vertical view also gets rotated to the same as the parentView1 (picture 3) immediately as I dropped the vertical view.  I do not want it to happen.  I need the red vertical view to rest in the same orientation from its original before it was dragged away.

The same effect also happens the other way around:  move a subview from parentView1 to outside it boundary if parentView1 has been rotated.

Any suggestion?

Code to rotate parentView1:

```
self.parentView1.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.parentView1.transform, degreesToRadians(45));
```

Code to move a view from a parent to another:

```
-(void)getNewPosition2:(UIView *)viewToConvert parentView:(UIView *)parentViewx superParentView:(UIView *)superParentView
{
    CGPoint newPoint = [superParentView convertPoint:viewToConvert.center fromView:parentViewx];
//    viewToConvert.layer.position = newPoint;
    viewToConvert.center = newPoint;
    [viewToConvert removeFromSuperview];
    [superParentView addSubview:viewToConvert];
}
```

Calling the getNewPostition2 method above:

```
[self getNewPosition2:recognizer.view parentView:self.view superParentView:self.parentView1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution by using the parentView1's transform matrix to calculate angle for both cases: moving object in and out of parentView1.

For moving object into parentView1:

```
float angle = (2 * M_PI) - atanf(self.parentView1.transform.b / self.parentView1.transform.a );
viewToConvert.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(viewToConvert.transform, angle);
```

For moving object out of parentView1:

```
float angle = atanf(self.parentView1.transform.b / self.parentView1.transform.a);
viewToConvert.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(viewToConvert.transform, angle);
```